# Java algorithm to check if one Line contains another line (defined by points)

Tags: java, algorithm, line

Does anybody know the algorithm to check whether two lines contains each other?

I have algorithm for intersection check but doesnt work for example:

```
line A (1,1) to (2,2)
line B (1,1) to (3,3)
```

Code:

```
double s1_x = this.getRightPoint().getX() - this.getLeftPoint().getX(),
        s1_y = this.getRightPoint().getY() - this.getLeftPoint().getY(),

        s2_x = other.getRightPoint().getX() - other.getLeftPoint().getX(),
        s2_y = other.getRightPoint().getY() - other.getLeftPoint().getY(),

        s = (-s1_y * (this.getLeftPoint().getX() - other.getLeftPoint().getX()) + s1_x * (this.getLeftPoint().getY() - other.getLeftPoint().getY())) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y),
        t = (s2_x * (this.getLeftPoint().getY() - other.getLeftPoint().getY()) - s2_y * (this.getLeftPoint().getX() - other.getLeftPoint().getX())) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

if (Double.valueOf(s).isNaN() && Double.valueOf(t).isNaN()) {
    return true;
}

if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
    // Collision detected
}

//s is NaN and t becomes NaN
```

Comment: if one contains other line, then slope is equal , and check slope of one point from one line and other point from other line r equal to slope of first slope

Answer (score 0):

The denominator of your `s` and `t` are zero.
Instead, try using this.
You know that two lines that "contains each other" will have the same gradient.
You can get gradient1 `m1=s1_y/s1_x` and gradient2 `m2=s2_y/s2_x`
Also the right point of the left line has to be located between right point and left point of the right line.
So it would be:

```
(other.getRightPoint().getX() >= this.getRightPoint().getX()) && (other.getRightPoint().getX()<= other.getLeftPoint().getX())
```

Combining that 2 fact will give you what you want.